# jquery parse xml from single and multiple tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Got a problem returning the text from an xml node. It all needs to be dynamic. Here is the xml:

```
<instructions>Some ins text.</instructions>
<options>
    <option>1.png</option>
    <option>2.png</option>
    <option>3.png</option>
    <option>4.png</option>
</options>
<noOfOptions>4</noOfOptions>
```

Here is the jquery parse code:

```
currentPageData.push({
    title:$(xml).find("page").attr("name"),
    noOfOptions:$(xml).find("noOfOptions").text(), 
    text:$(xml).find("text").text(), 
    instructions:$(xml).find("instructions").text(), 
    option:$(xml).find("option").each(function() {
        $(this).text();
    }),
```

The problem is the option section. This just returns one object. I think this is because of the .each function. But I need all of them, that are present to be returned and i need it to return the text in a for loop like this:

```
for(i=0;i<noOfOptions;i++) {
    currentPageData[0].option[0];
}
```

The above is not working. How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the text content of your option nodes try this....

Firstly, your xml isn't valid. I've added a root node

```
var xml = "<root>
               <instructions>Some ins text.</instructions>
               <options>
                   <option>1.png</option>
                   <option>2.png</option>
                   <option>3.png</option>
                   <option>4.png</option>
               </options>
               <noOfOptions>4</noOfOptions>
           </root>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $options = $xml.find("option"); // get all option nodes
```

Then to get each option value using jquery .each

```
$.each($options, function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Hope that helps

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/JohnMcNulty/vRf9Z/

Comment: Shouldn't the last line of the parsexml in the first code section abov?e be $options = $xml.find("options"); // get all option nodes? i.e.

Comment: Hi @Chiwda have you looked at the fiddle?

Comment: OK. I get it now.  option is the sub-element of options.  Thanx!