# jquery parse xml for multiple tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, parsexml

I want to get multiple tags from an XML document. I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350254/jquery-parse-xml-from-single-and-multiple-tags) which essentially gets sub-elements of one tag, whereas I want all the tags.  Using the same example XML (replicated below):

```
var data = 
"<root>
    <instructions>Some ins text.</instructions>
    <options>
       <option>1.png</option>
       <option>2.png</option>
       <option>3.png</option>
       <option>4.png</option>
    </options>
    <noOfOptions>4</noOfOptions>
</root>";
```

How do I get the values for "instructions", "options" and "noOfOptions"?

I could just repeat the code three times like this:

```
xml = $.parseXML(data),
$data = $( xml ),
$options = $data.find("option"); // get all option nodes

xml = $.parseXML(data),
$data = $( xml ),
$instructions = $xml.find("instructions"); // get instructions

xml = $.parseXML(data),
$data = $( xml ),
$noOfOptions = $xml.find("noOfOptions"); // get noOfOptions
```

But that doesn't seem right. Is there a correct (and more efficient) way to do this?  I think the .each function has something to do with it, but don't really understand how to use it.

Comment: Is there only one `instructions` and mutliple `options`?

Comment: No necessarily.  In fact most of time, I will not need to go down a level.

Comment: I'm concerned about the number of `instructions` because in my answer I assumed there will be just one. if it could be more then you should make an array of them just the like for `option`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var data = 
"<root>\
    <instructions>Some ins text.</instructions>\
    <options>\
       <option>1.png</option>\
       <option>2.png</option>\
       <option>3.png</option>\
       <option>4.png</option>\
    </options>\
    <noOfOptions>4</noOfOptions>\
</root>";


var xml = $.parseXML(data);
var $data = $( xml );

var instructions = $data.find("instructions").text();
var options = [];
$data.find("option").each(function(){
  options.push($(this).text());
});

console.log("instructions: " + instructions);
console.log("options: ", options);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your structure is fixed, You can try this:

```
 var data = 
"<root>"+
    "<instructions>Some ins text.</instructions>"+
    "<options>"+
      " <option>1.png</option>"+
       "<option>2.png</option>"+
      " <option>3.png</option>"+
      " <option>4.png</option>"+
   " </options>"+
   " <noOfOptions>4</noOfOptions>"+
   "<instructions>Some ins text1.</instructions>"+
   "<options>"+
     " <option>1.png</option>"+
      "<option>2.png</option>"+
     " <option>3.png</option>"+
     " <option>4.png</option>"+
  " </options>"+
  " <noOfOptions>4</noOfOptions>"+
"</root>";
xml = $.parseXML(data);
var arr=[];
    var arr=[];
    $("instructions", xml).each(function (index,val) {

        arr[index]=[];
        arr[index]['instructions']=$(this).text();
        arr[index]['option']=[];
        $("option",$(val).next()).each(function(){
            arr[index]['option'].push($(this).text());
        });
        arr[index]['noOfOptions']=[];
        arr[index]['noOfOptions']=$($(val).next()).next().text();

        });
    console.log(arr);
```

**Console OUTPUT:**

> [Array[0], Array[0]]0: Array[0]instructions: "Some ins text."length:
>   0noOfOptions: "4"option: Array[4]**proto**: Array[0]1: Array[0]length:
>   2__proto__: Array[0]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bu8a33n2/1/)

If you need the entire data as json(can vbe converted in jquery array/object) you can use: [xml2json](http://dfsq.github.io/xml2json/#.WI7gsx9NxNw)